# High CPU usage on Cloud SQL causing timeouts

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql

We have a postres database that has billions of records in it.

We have one client that uses our older API to query the database to fetch thousands of records once a day.
I would say close to the top end of the thousands.

The API is currently on a compute engine behind a load balancer and during the allotted time I spin up 6 instances of this to attempt to help handle the load.

What I have found is that the CPU usage on cloud SQL is maxing out at 100% and most of the other stats are fine, it's just the CPU.

This basically renders our API useless as we can't accept connections and it just shits its self.

What can we do to help this?

Here is the CPU utilisation chart
[image]

And the connections
[image]

Read/Writes
[image]

Memory Usage
[image]

You can see in most of the other charts the readings are well within normal for what we expect.

I don't really want to have to beef up the CPU usage if it isn't really the actual underlining problem.

A further thing to note is we have developed a new endpoint for this client specifically to use, they have not got that in place yet, and there is no guarantee that it will reduce the db load.

Comment: Having 100% CPU utilization should not prevent new connections from being accepted.  It would only make them run slower.  It sounds like your application was designed to shoot itself in the head at the slightest inconvenience.  Maybe you should change that.

Answer (score 0):

High CPU usage can most definitely cause dropped or ignored connections. The database engine and underlying OS are fighting for resources and aren't able to respond to the connection in time.

While you can increase CPU usage, it looks like the CPU usage you have it (usually) enough, except during parts where the CPU is at 100%. I'd suggest instead finding out why the query is eating so much CPU usage and optimizing it.

You might be interested in something like [Cloud SQL Insights](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/databases/get-ahead-of-database-performance-issues-with-cloud-sql-insights) to help debug the query.

Comment: thank you for this.
i shall look further into the insights.

Comment: on further investigation, it looks like we are hitting the some type of rate limiting "Error 429: Quota exceeded for quota metric 'Queries' and limit 'Queries per minute per user' of service 'sqladmin.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:367688803283'., rateLimitExceeded". We are not using vpc yet (the db wasn't initially setup to have it)

Comment: Where are you seeing this error? Are you calling the SQL Admin API?